# Add paypal payment confirmation to mysql after form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a very simple online html form . The user fills in a form, and when they submit, it inserts the info into a MySQL database, then redirects them to PayPal to complete the payment. The problem is that the database does not have any information about whether they actually completed the payment.

The solution to this was to use IPN. I have search online and you-tube for tutorials but it was too complicated and i couldn't achieve the IPN to confirm payment into MySQL.

Kindly I ask if anyone can help me put this together.

Comment: In order to secure your payments with Paypal using the IPN is kind of mandatory. You want to handle your payments securely and not using the IPN takes you away from a secure app. So I suggest you go deeper into the IPN research and try implement it. Actually it's not even that hard - You simply have to submit the _notifiy_url_ including the location where Paypal will send you information about the transaction which you can review and act based on it; This is where you actually wanna store the database row. http://goo.gl/Si4OC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too complicated.

You got a sandbox account for testing already? If not, signup for seller/buyer test-account at [sandbox.paypal.com](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home). Maybe need different e-mail addresses for both, not sure.

1.) In your submit form enter the path to your IPN script e.g. `pp.notifiy.php`

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://my.test/pp.notifiy.php" />
```

Also in your PayPal merchant/sandbox account settings, specify the URL of your listener.
The listener script must not be firewalled. It will receive $_POST from PayPal.

2.) After successful payment,

- Paypal will post to your listener script (e.g. pp.notifiy.php)
- and the listener would post a duplicate of the post-stuff back.
- You are checking the body for the string `VERIFIED` to process the order and update your db.

I prefer the cURL solution, as PayPal had changes recently, which caused some troubles, with the cURL solution it worked fine for me especially when sandbox testing. Need [cURL extension to be active in PHP](http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/).

For the cURL solution, read more on PayPal Developer: [How To Process Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Messages](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/); the other solution, which I'd NOT recommend [uses fsockopen](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/).

Here are parts of my working cURL listener script (pp.notify.php)

```
#$pp_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$pp_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

// build the request / postback
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach($_POST AS $k => $v) {
  $v=urlencode(stripslashes($v));
  $req.="&$k=$v";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate using curl
$ch = curl_init($pp_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if(!($res=curl_exec($ch)))
{
  #error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
  curl_close($ch);
  exit;
}

$res = trim($res);
curl_close($ch);

// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if(strcmp($res,"VERIFIED")==0)
{
  // The IPN is verified
  // update your db/process order...

} else if (strcmp($res,"INVALID")==0)
{
  // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
}
```

This would work on the sandbox too. So best to do a couple of tests. You should get the `VERIFIED` and then process the order/update db. When all works fine, switch from sandbox to real PayPal and best to test that too at least once.

I hope this helps for getting started!

Comment: Thank you i am working on this and i have one question: <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://my.test/pp.notifiy.php" /> is placed with the button or the form? because the form is on one page and the next page is the paypal button

Comment: Place it in the form, where all the variables are posted to PayPal (business, item_name, currency_code, amount,...). The value of `notify_url` is the URL to your listener script, starting with http://...

Comment: I have one concern, the form is sent to database then redirected to pay options,

Comment: Just be sure, to post it to PayPal. `<form name="order" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"> ... somewhere here` should be fine.

Comment: @Loading Welcome :) Happy you got it going.