# Paypal IPN not called with sandbox

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to create the Paypal IPN script so that I can update my database after the user's payment.

I downloaded a script on github and only inserted mail() inside, so that I can receive an email on each step - for now.

The problem is: when I make the payment with sandbox, it seems the IPN script is never called, because I never receive anything.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Also had issues with sandbox testing when using fsockopen. [See here for a curl solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22584848/3110638) how it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove statements that are not constructive. I would recommend you to edit your question and provide any more detail available in order get help. Good luck!

Comment: I already use curl... but it seems nothing happens.

Comment: I used the code that you gave and it's the same thing: the problem is that I added error_logs everywhere, but when I open the error log file, it's empty !!!

Comment: I added a line that sends me an email, at the top of the ipn file. When I open it in a browser, I receive the email. When I make the payment (Paypal should call the ipn script and I should receive the email), nothing happens, I don't receive the test email... Is there anyone who could help me? It's pretty urgent and I'm completely stuck...

Comment: Check this answer it might be your solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623691/paypal-ipn-response-not-getting-into-android-mobile-browser/32628405#32628405