# Paypal IPN response not getting into Android Mobile Browser

Tags: php, android, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am new to Paypal integration, and I am trying to implement Paypal IPN for my android application. For make it working, I have created one web-page (Using PHP and sending to Paypal sandbox account , method (GET) ) in that I am doing  payment. And I am getting payment status from this.

Actually this web page working properly and get response after do payment into Computer Browser but same thing if I am doing payment with Android Mobile browser then I am not getting any response form the Paypal for payment I have did.

I am using this url
[IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Here is my HTML code.

```
      <form name="payment_form" id="payment_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="GET" onSubmit="return form_submit();">
      <input type="text" name="amount"  id="amount" value="1" readonly class="form-control left-icon">
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="cmd" value="_xclick">
      <input type="hidden" readonly  name="business" value="Bmlpatel@gmail.com">
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="item_name" value="TEST Store">
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="LC" value="AL"> 
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="country" value="USA">
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="quantity" value="1"> 
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="notify_url" value="http://XX.111.XXX.XX/payment/response.php">
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="return" value="http://XX.111.XXX.XX/payment/response.php">
      <input type="hidden" readonly name="cancel_url" value="http://XX.111.XXX.XX/payment/">
      <input class="btn btn-success" name="action" value="Recharge" type="submit">
      </form>
```

So any help to this topic appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue ...

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure you have IPN turned on in your PayPal settings:

- Log into your PayPal account and go to Profile → Profile & Settings →
  Selling Preferences → Instant Payment Notification preferences:
  (alternatively [click here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify) to go directly to the page, making sure
  you're logged into your PayPal account before you click the link)
- Click Turn On IPN on the PayPal site.
- You will then be prompted for a Notification URL, which should be
  any URL - it will only be replaced by your `notify_url` parameter
- Save your settings

If you've already done this then you need to make sure your Notification URL is accessible via the outside world, you look like you're using an IP so using something like https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy to check your site is definitely available.

If all else fails it may be an issue with PayPal and the way it decodes the `notify_url` from Android web browsers. I have this issue with them and sometimes the `notify_url` is cut short - and we suspect it's only on Android browsers.

Check your [IPN history](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history) on your PayPal account and you'll see the exact URL the IPN was sent to and the status.

Comment: I am unable to login, because i am using sandbox account for login in to paypal account. I have only sandbox account for testing. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes Sandbox account is a PayPal account, except it's sandboxed. You can log in just like a normal PayPal account.